# Как создавать и читать xml файлы в java?

Tags: xml, java

Как создавать и читать xml файлы в java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Чтение XML в Java с помощью DOM](http://javaswing.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/java_dom_xml/)
- [XML и Java: Три подхода к сохранению XML](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-xjavaforum5/index.html)
- [Запись данных в файл .xml](http://javatalks.ru/sutra98942.php&sid=89a5c425853badf5fbbf19f2f1eebc49)